# Adding an ID or class to Marker using markerwithlabel class

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var markers = new MarkerWithLabel({
  position: point,
  icon: imagePath1,
  map: map,
  draggable: false,
  labelContent: image_count,
  labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 30),
  labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
  labelInBackground: false,
  id: "markerId",
  title : contentVal,

});


alert("Id is::"+$("#"+markers.id).val());
```

When I try to get Id, it is undefined

Comment: what is `MarkerWithLabel`? Can you give definition of it?

Comment: It is a class. to plot terminal Marker with label on Google MAP

Comment: are you shure it has public id property?

Comment: I googled it and found id property somewhere.  
    Is there any way to add Id /Class as a new property?

Answer (score 0):

I too hit this roadblock. I reviewed the source code for `MarkerWithLabel`, and it does *not* support setting the `ID` or `Class`.

But you can add support by changing just 3 lines of code. Below is the modified code, with my added "ID" support. It works as normal, but if you add a `.id` property when creating a `new MarkerWithLabel` (as you did above), it will properly set the ID.

### New markerswithlabel.js code — Added ID Support

```
/**
 * @name MarkerWithLabel for V3
 * @version 1.1.10 [April 8, 2014]
 * @author Gary Little (inspired by code from Marc Ridey of Google).
 * @copyright Copyright 2012 Gary Little [gary at luxcentral.com]
 * @fileoverview MarkerWithLabel extends the Google Maps JavaScript API V3
 *  <code>google.maps.Marker</code> class.
 *  <p>
 *  MarkerWithLabel allows you to define markers with associated labels. As you would expect,
 *  if the marker is draggable, so too will be the label. In addition, a marker with a label
 *  responds to all mouse events in the same manner as a regular marker. It also fires mouse
 *  events and "property changed" events just as a regular marker would. Version 1.1 adds
 *  support for the raiseOnDrag feature introduced in API V3.3.
 *  <p>
 *  If you drag a marker by its label, you can cancel the drag and return the marker to its
 *  original position by pressing the <code>Esc</code> key. This doesn't work if you drag the marker
 *  itself because this feature is not (yet) supported in the <code>google.maps.Marker</code> class.
 */

/*!
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

/*jslint browser:true */
/*global document,google */

/**
 * @param {Function} childCtor Child class.
 * @param {Function} parentCtor Parent class.
 * @private
 */
function inherits(childCtor, parentCtor) {
  /* @constructor */
  function tempCtor() {}
  tempCtor.prototype = parentCtor.prototype;
  childCtor.superClass_ = parentCtor.prototype;
  childCtor.prototype = new tempCtor();
  /* @override */
  childCtor.prototype.constructor = childCtor;
}

/**
 * This constructor creates a label and associates it with a marker.
 * It is for the private use of the MarkerWithLabel class.
 * @constructor
 * @param {Marker} marker The marker with which the label is to be associated.
 * @param {string} crossURL The URL of the cross image =.
 * @param {string} handCursor The URL of the hand cursor.
 * @private
 */
function MarkerLabel_(id, marker, crossURL, handCursorURL) {
  this.marker_ = marker;
  this.handCursorURL_ = marker.handCursorURL;

  this.labelDiv_ = document.createElement("div");

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // New - ID support
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (typeof id !== 'undefined') this.labelDiv_.id = id;


  this.labelDiv_.style.cssText = "position: absolute; overflow: hidden;";

  // Get the DIV for the "X" to be displayed when the marker is raised.
  this.crossDiv_ = MarkerLabel_.getSharedCross(crossURL);
}

inherits(MarkerLabel_, google.maps.OverlayView);

/**
 * Returns the DIV for the cross used when dragging a marker when the
 * raiseOnDrag parameter set to true. One cross is shared with all markers.
 * @param {string} crossURL The URL of the cross image =.
 * @private
 */
MarkerLabel_.getSharedCross = function (crossURL) {
  var div;
  if (typeof MarkerLabel_.getSharedCross.crossDiv === "undefined") {
    div = document.createElement("img");
    div.style.cssText = "position: absolute; z-index: 1000002; display: none;";
    // Hopefully Google never changes the standard "X" attributes:
    div.style.marginLeft = "-8px";
    div.style.marginTop = "-9px";
    div.src = crossURL;
    MarkerLabel_.getSharedCross.crossDiv = div;
  }
  return MarkerLabel_.getSharedCross.crossDiv;
};

/**
 * Adds the DIV representing the label to the DOM. This method is called
 * automatically when the marker's <code>setMap</code> method is called.
 * @private
 */
MarkerLabel_.prototype.onAdd = function () {
  var me = this;
  var cMouseIsDown = false;
  var cDraggingLabel = false;
  var cSavedZIndex;
  var cLatOffset, cLngOffset;
  var cIgnoreClick;
  var cRaiseEnabled;
  var cStartPosition;
  var cStartCenter;
  // Constants:
  var cRaiseOffset = 20;
  var cDraggingCursor = "url(" + this.handCursorURL_ + ")";

  // Stops all processing of an event.
  //
  var cAbortEvent = function (e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  };

  var cStopBounce = function () {
    me.marker_.setAnimation(null);
  };

  this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(this.labelDiv_);
  // One cross is shared with all markers, so only add it once:
  if (typeof MarkerLabel_.getSharedCross.processed === "undefined") {
    this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(this.crossDiv_);
    MarkerLabel_.getSharedCross.processed = true;
  }

  this.listeners_ = [
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.labelDiv_, "mouseover", function (e) {
      if (me.marker_.getDraggable() || me.marker_.getClickable()) {
        this.style.cursor = "pointer";
        google.maps.event.trigger(me.marker_, "mouseover", e);
      }
    }),
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.labelDiv_, "mouseout", function (e) {
      if ((me.marker_.getDraggable() || me.marker_.getClickable()) && !cDraggingLabel) {
        this.style.cursor = me.marker_.getCursor();
        google.maps.event.trigger(me.marker_, "mouseout", e);
      }
    }),
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.labelDiv_, "mousedown", function (e) {
      cDraggingLabel = false;
      if (me.marker_.getDraggable()) {
        cMouseIsDown = true;
        this.style.cursor = cDraggingCursor;
      }
      if (me.marker_.getDraggable() || me.marker_.getClickable()) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(me.marker_, "mousedown", e);
        cAbortEvent(e); // Prevent map pan when starting a drag on a label
      }
    }),
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document, "mouseup", function (mEvent) {
      var position;
      if (cMouseIsDown) {
        cMouseIsDown = false;
        me.eventDiv_.style.cursor = "pointer";
        google.maps.event.trigger(me.marker_, "mouseup", mEvent);
      }
      if (cDraggingLabel) {
        if (cRaiseEnabled) { // Lower the marker & label
          position = me.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(me.marker_.getPosition());
          position.y += cRaiseOffset;
          me.marker_.setPosition(me.getProjection().fromDivPixelToLatLng(position));
          // This is not the same bouncing style as when the marker portion is dragged,
          // but it will have to do:
          try { // Will fail if running Google Maps API earlier than V3.3
            me.marker_.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
            setTimeout(cStopBounce, 1406);
          } catch (e) {}
        }
        me.crossDiv_.style.display = "none";
        me.marker_.setZIndex(cSavedZIndex);
        cIgnoreClick = true; // Set flag to ignore the click event reported after a label drag
        cDraggingLabel = false;
        mEvent.latLng = me.marker_.getPosition();
        google.maps.event.trigger(me.marker_, "dragend", mEvent);
      }
    }),
    google.maps.event.addListener(me.marker_.getMap(), "mousemove", function (mEvent) {
      var position;
      if (cMouseIsDown) {
        if (cDraggingLabel) {
          // Change the reported location from the mouse position to the marker position:
          mEvent.latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(mEvent.latLng.lat() - cLatOffset, mEvent.latLng.lng() - cLngOffset);
          position = me.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(mEvent.latLng);
          if (cRaiseEnabled) {
            me.crossDiv_.style.left = position.x + "px";
            me.crossDiv_.style.top = position.y + "px";
            me.crossDiv_.style.display = "";
            position.y -= cRaiseOffset;
          }
          me.marker_.setPosition(me.getProjection().fromDivPixelToLatLng(position));
          if (cRaiseEnabled) { // Don't raise the veil; this hack needed to make MSIE act properly
            me.eventDiv_.style.top = (position.y + cRaiseOffset) + "px";
          }
          google.maps.event.trigger(me.marker_, "drag", mEvent);
        } else {
          // Calculate offsets from the click point to the marker position:
          cLatOffset = mEvent.latLng.lat() - me.marker_.getPosition().lat();
          cLngOffset = mEvent.latLng.lng() - me.marker_.getPosition().lng();
          cSavedZIndex = me.marker_.getZIndex();
          cStartPosition = me.marker_.getPosition();
          cStartCenter = me.marker_.getMap().getCenter();
          cRaiseEnabled = me.marker_.get("raiseOnDrag");
          cDraggingLabel = true;
          me.marker_.setZIndex(1000000); // Moves the marker & label to the foreground during a drag
          mEvent.latLng = me.marker_.getPosition();
          google.maps.event.trigger(me.marker_, "dragstart", mEvent);
        }
      }
    }),
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document, "keydown", function (e) {
      if (cDraggingLabel) {
        if (e.keyCode === 27) { // Esc key
          cRaiseEnabled = false;
          me.marker_.setPosition(cStartPosition);
          me.marker_.getMap().setCenter(cStartCenter);
          google.maps.event.trigger(document, "mouseup", e);
        }
      }
    }),
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.labelDiv_, "click", function (e) {
      if (me.marker_.getDraggable() || me.marker_.getClickable()) {
        if (cIgnoreClick) { // Ignore the click reported when a label drag ends
          cIgnoreClick = false;
        } else {
          google.maps.event.trigger(me.marker_, "click", e);
          cAbortEvent(e); // Prevent click from being passed on to map
        }
      }
    }),
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.labelDiv_, "dblclick", function (e) {
      if (me.marker_.getDraggable() || me.marker_.getClickable()) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(me.marker_, "dblclick", e);
        cAbortEvent(e); // Prevent map zoom when double-clicking on a label
      }
    }),
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker_, "dragstart", function (mEvent) {
      if (!cDraggingLabel) {
        cRaiseEnabled = this.get("raiseOnDrag");
      }
    }),
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker_, "drag", function (mEvent) {
      if (!cDraggingLabel) {
        if (cRaiseEnabled) {
          me.setPosition(cRaiseOffset);
          // During a drag, the marker's z-index is temporarily set to 1000000 to
          // ensure it appears above all other markers. Also set the label's z-index
          // to 1000000 (plus or minus 1 depending on whether the label is supposed
          // to be above or below the marker).
          me.labelDiv_.style.zIndex = 1000000 + (this.get("labelInBackground") ? -1 : +1);
        }
      }
    }),
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker_, "dragend", function (mEvent) {
      if (!cDraggingLabel) {
        if (cRaiseEnabled) {
          me.setPosition(0); // Also restores z-index of label
        }
      }
    }),
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker_, "position_changed", function () {
      me.setPosition();
    }),
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker_, "zindex_changed", function () {
      me.setZIndex();
    }),
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker_, "visible_changed", function () {
      me.setVisible();
    }),
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker_, "labelvisible_changed", function () {
      me.setVisible();
    }),
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker_, "title_changed", function () {
      me.setTitle();
    }),
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker_, "labelcontent_changed", function () {
      me.setContent();
    }),
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker_, "labelanchor_changed", function () {
      me.setAnchor();
    }),
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker_, "labelclass_changed", function () {
      me.setStyles();
    }),
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker_, "labelstyle_changed", function () {
      me.setStyles();
    })
  ];
};

/**
 * Removes the DIV for the label from the DOM. It also removes all event handlers.
 * This method is called automatically when the marker's <code>setMap(null)</code>
 * method is called.
 * @private
 */
MarkerLabel_.prototype.onRemove = function () {
  var i;
  this.labelDiv_.parentNode.removeChild(this.labelDiv_);

  // Remove event listeners:
  for (i = 0; i < this.listeners_.length; i++) {
    google.maps.event.removeListener(this.listeners_[i]);
  }
};

/**
 * Draws the label on the map.
 * @private
 */
MarkerLabel_.prototype.draw = function () {
  this.setContent();
  this.setTitle();
  this.setStyles();
};

/**
 * Sets the content of the label.
 * The content can be plain text or an HTML DOM node.
 * @private
 */
MarkerLabel_.prototype.setContent = function () {
  var content = this.marker_.get("labelContent");
  if (typeof content.nodeType === "undefined") {
    this.labelDiv_.innerHTML = content;
  } else {
    this.labelDiv_.innerHTML = ""; // Remove current content
    this.labelDiv_.appendChild(content);
  }
};

/**
 * Sets the content of the tool tip for the label. It is
 * always set to be the same as for the marker itself.
 * @private
 */
MarkerLabel_.prototype.setTitle = function () {
   this.labelDiv_.title = this.marker_.getTitle() || "";
};

/**
 * Sets the style of the label by setting the style sheet and applying
 * other specific styles requested.
 * @private
 */
MarkerLabel_.prototype.setStyles = function () {
  var i, labelStyle;

  // Apply style values from the style sheet defined in the labelClass parameter:
  this.labelDiv_.className = this.marker_.get("labelClass");

  // Clear existing inline style values:
  this.labelDiv_.style.cssText = "";
  // Apply style values defined in the labelStyle parameter:
  labelStyle = this.marker_.get("labelStyle");
  for (i in labelStyle) {
    if (labelStyle.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      this.labelDiv_.style[i] = labelStyle[i];
    }
  }
  this.setMandatoryStyles();
};

/**
 * Sets the mandatory styles to the DIV representing the label as well as to the
 * associated event DIV. This includes setting the DIV position, z-index, and visibility.
 * @private
 */
MarkerLabel_.prototype.setMandatoryStyles = function () {
  this.labelDiv_.style.position = "absolute";
  this.labelDiv_.style.overflow = "hidden";
  // Make sure the opacity setting causes the desired effect on MSIE:
  if (typeof this.labelDiv_.style.opacity !== "undefined" && this.labelDiv_.style.opacity !== "") {
    this.labelDiv_.style.MsFilter = "\"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=" + (this.labelDiv_.style.opacity * 100) + ")\"";
    this.labelDiv_.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + (this.labelDiv_.style.opacity * 100) + ")";
  }

  this.setAnchor();
  this.setPosition(); // This also updates z-index, if necessary.
  this.setVisible();
};

/**
 * Sets the anchor point of the label.
 * @private
 */
MarkerLabel_.prototype.setAnchor = function () {
  var anchor = this.marker_.get("labelAnchor");
  this.labelDiv_.style.marginLeft = -anchor.x + "px";
  this.labelDiv_.style.marginTop = -anchor.y + "px";
};

/**
 * Sets the position of the label. The z-index is also updated, if necessary.
 * @private
 */
MarkerLabel_.prototype.setPosition = function (yOffset) {
  var position = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.marker_.getPosition());
  if (typeof yOffset === "undefined") {
    yOffset = 0;
  }
  this.labelDiv_.style.left = Math.round(position.x) + "px";
  this.labelDiv_.style.top = Math.round(position.y - yOffset) + "px";

  this.setZIndex();
};

/**
 * Sets the z-index of the label. If the marker's z-index property has not been defined, the z-index
 * of the label is set to the vertical coordinate of the label. This is in keeping with the default
 * stacking order for Google Maps: markers to the south are in front of markers to the north.
 * @private
 */
MarkerLabel_.prototype.setZIndex = function () {
  var zAdjust = (this.marker_.get("labelInBackground") ? -1 : +1);
  if (typeof this.marker_.getZIndex() === "undefined") {
    this.labelDiv_.style.zIndex = parseInt(this.labelDiv_.style.top, 10) + zAdjust;
  } else {
    this.labelDiv_.style.zIndex = this.marker_.getZIndex() + zAdjust;
  }
};

/**
 * Sets the visibility of the label. The label is visible only if the marker itself is
 * visible (i.e., its visible property is true) and the labelVisible property is true.
 * @private
 */
MarkerLabel_.prototype.setVisible = function () {
  if (this.marker_.get("labelVisible")) {
    this.labelDiv_.style.display = this.marker_.getVisible() ? "block" : "none";
  } else {
    this.labelDiv_.style.display = "none";
  }
};

/**
 * @name MarkerWithLabelOptions
 * @class This class represents the optional parameter passed to the {@link MarkerWithLabel} constructor.
 *  The properties available are the same as for <code>google.maps.Marker</code> with the addition
 *  of the properties listed below. To change any of these additional properties after the labeled
 *  marker has been created, call <code>google.maps.Marker.set(propertyName, propertyValue)</code>.
 *  <p>
 *  When any of these properties changes, a property changed event is fired. The names of these
 *  events are derived from the name of the property and are of the form <code>propertyname_changed</code>.
 *  For example, if the content of the label changes, a <code>labelcontent_changed</code> event
 *  is fired.
 *  <p>
 * @property {string|Node} [labelContent] The content of the label (plain text or an HTML DOM node).
 * @property {Point} [labelAnchor] By default, a label is drawn with its anchor point at (0,0) so
 *  that its top left corner is positioned at the anchor point of the associated marker. Use this
 *  property to change the anchor point of the label. For example, to center a 50px-wide label
 *  beneath a marker, specify a <code>labelAnchor</code> of <code>google.maps.Point(25, 0)</code>.
 *  (Note: x-values increase to the right and y-values increase to the top.)
 * @property {string} [labelClass] The name of the CSS class defining the styles for the label.
 *  Note that style values for <code>position</code>, <code>overflow</code>, <code>top</code>,
 *  <code>left</code>, <code>zIndex</code>, <code>display</code>, <code>marginLeft</code>, and
 *  <code>marginTop</code> are ignored; these styles are for internal use only.
 * @property {Object} [labelStyle] An object literal whose properties define specific CSS
 *  style values to be applied to the label. Style values defined here override those that may
 *  be defined in the <code>labelClass</code> style sheet. If this property is changed after the
 *  label has been created, all previously set styles (except those defined in the style sheet)
 *  are removed from the label before the new style values are applied.
 *  Note that style values for <code>position</code>, <code>overflow</code>, <code>top</code>,
 *  <code>left</code>, <code>zIndex</code>, <code>display</code>, <code>marginLeft</code>, and
 *  <code>marginTop</code> are ignored; these styles are for internal use only.
 * @property {boolean} [labelInBackground] A flag indicating whether a label that overlaps its
 *  associated marker should appear in the background (i.e., in a plane below the marker).
 *  The default is <code>false</code>, which causes the label to appear in the foreground.
 * @property {boolean} [labelVisible] A flag indicating whether the label is to be visible.
 *  The default is <code>true</code>. Note that even if <code>labelVisible</code> is
 *  <code>true</code>, the label will <i>not</i> be visible unless the associated marker is also
 *  visible (i.e., unless the marker's <code>visible</code> property is <code>true</code>).
 * @property {boolean} [raiseOnDrag] A flag indicating whether the label and marker are to be
 *  raised when the marker is dragged. The default is <code>true</code>. If a draggable marker is
 *  being created and a version of Google Maps API earlier than V3.3 is being used, this property
 *  must be set to <code>false</code>.
 * @property {boolean} [optimized] A flag indicating whether rendering is to be optimized for the
 *  marker. <b>Important: The optimized rendering technique is not supported by MarkerWithLabel,
 *  so the value of this parameter is always forced to <code>false</code>.
 * @property {string} [crossImage="http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/drag_cross_67_16.png"]
 *  The URL of the cross image to be displayed while dragging a marker.
 * @property {string} [handCursor="http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/closedhand_8_8.cur"]
 *  The URL of the cursor to be displayed while dragging a marker.
 */
/**
 * Creates a MarkerWithLabel with the options specified in {@link MarkerWithLabelOptions}.
 * @constructor
 * @param {MarkerWithLabelOptions} [opt_options] The optional parameters.
 */
function MarkerWithLabel(opt_options) {
  opt_options = opt_options || {};

  opt_options.labelContent = opt_options.labelContent || "";
  opt_options.labelAnchor = opt_options.labelAnchor || new google.maps.Point(0, 0);
  opt_options.labelClass = opt_options.labelClass || "markerLabels";
  opt_options.labelStyle = opt_options.labelStyle || {};
  opt_options.labelInBackground = opt_options.labelInBackground || false;
  if (typeof opt_options.labelVisible === "undefined") {
    opt_options.labelVisible = true;
  }
  if (typeof opt_options.raiseOnDrag === "undefined") {
    opt_options.raiseOnDrag = true;
  }
  if (typeof opt_options.clickable === "undefined") {
    opt_options.clickable = true;
  }
  if (typeof opt_options.draggable === "undefined") {
    opt_options.draggable = false;
  }
  if (typeof opt_options.optimized === "undefined") {
    opt_options.optimized = false;
  }
  opt_options.crossImage = opt_options.crossImage || "http" + (document.location.protocol === "https:" ? "s" : "") + "://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/drag_cross_67_16.png";
  opt_options.handCursor = opt_options.handCursor || "http" + (document.location.protocol === "https:" ? "s" : "") + "://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/closedhand_8_8.cur";
  opt_options.optimized = false; // Optimized rendering is not supported


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // New
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  this.label = new MarkerLabel_(opt_options.id, this, opt_options.crossImage, opt_options.handCursor); // Bind the label to the marker



  // Call the parent constructor. It calls Marker.setValues to initialize, so all
  // the new parameters are conveniently saved and can be accessed with get/set.
  // Marker.set triggers a property changed event (called "propertyname_changed")
  // that the marker label listens for in order to react to state changes.
  google.maps.Marker.apply(this, arguments);
}

inherits(MarkerWithLabel, google.maps.Marker);

/**
 * Overrides the standard Marker setMap function.
 * @param {Map} theMap The map to which the marker is to be added.
 * @private
 */
MarkerWithLabel.prototype.setMap = function (theMap) {

  // Call the inherited function...
  google.maps.Marker.prototype.setMap.apply(this, arguments);

  // ... then deal with the label:
  this.label.setMap(theMap);
};
```

If you would like to compress/minify/uglify the code, I recommend https://javascript-minifier.com/